# How to remove files and folders to trash? (qt)

Tags: file, qt, directory, recycle-bin

I am intresting in it for Windows, Mac OS and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a class doesn't exist to handle all thing automatically.

You can write your own class using ifdefs macros to toggle actions depending on compile platform